# How to set valueAxes title as variable from JSON in amCharts?

Tags: json, amcharts

I would like to change the valueAxes title from a hardcoded string to a value from a JSON property via dataprovider.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `init` event to set your valueAxes title then call `validateNow(true)` (or `validateData()`). Here's a contrived example:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "valueAxisTitle": "Number of visits", //can be whatever property you want
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 2025
  }, // ...
  ]
  // ...
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "init",
    "method": function(e) {
      e.chart.valueAxes[0].title = e.chart.dataProvider[0].valueAxisTitle;
      e.chart.validateNow(true);
    }
  }]
});
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/5160dd97014545a325cfefc1cf9a978f?editors=0010)

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for!